# Remove xarray metadata

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, python-xarray

I have the output of a certain operation in python xarray. I want only the output value(5.016678).
How do I remove the all the other text from the output? 
I am just using print to get the output.

Output:

```
<xarray.DataArray ()>
array(5.016678, dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
    XLONG    float32 91.59026
    XLAT     float32 26.100395
    XTIME    float32 23100.0
    Time     datetime64[ns] 2018-04-01T01:00:00
    level    int32 86 <xarray.DataArray ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `da.item()` to return the scalar value